# Scala.js convert Scala function to JS function

Tags: scala.js

I know that implicit conversions are available for `js.FunctionN` <–> `scala.FunctionN`. However, if I work with libraries in dynamic fashion (without typed facade), they won't help me, because the compiler obviously doesn't know that I need a conversion. For example, if a JS code expects a JS Array with a string and a function as an input -- something like

```
['Hello world', function ($x, $y) {
    console.log($x + $y)
}],
```

, I can't create it in Scala like this:

```
    val a: js.Array[Any] = js.Array(
      "Hello world",
      (x: Int, y: Int) => {console.log(x + y)}
    )
  )
```

Because Scala function will not be converted to JS function. Does there exist some explicit conversion method for that, similar to `toJSArray` for mutable Seq? I've checked that `asInstanceOf[js.Function]` doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`asInstanceOf` doesn't work because that is basically saying "this function is *already* a `js.Function`", which isn't true. But this does usually convert correctly if you give it an explicit type ascription, like this (haven't tried compiling but should be roughly correct):

```
val a: js.Array[Any] = js.Array(
  "Hello world",
  { (x: Int, y: Int) => {console.log(x + y)} }:js.Function2[Int, Int, Unit]
)
```

It's a bit more boilerplate, but that's always the cost of going without facades...

Comment: You can make it less boilerplaty by ascribing as `: js.Function` rather than the `js.Function2[...]` verbose thing. But otherwise, yes, that's pretty much what you have to do.